# How to create mobile friendly split views or panes supports using js or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create adjustable split views or panes supports that are also mobile friendly.

What I mean is that split view is automatically shows side-by-side on desktop but changes to top-by-bottom on a mobile phone?

After researching I've found [Split.js](https://github.com/nathancahill/Split.js/) but it doesn't support mobile views. I can always create and destroy views by watching `window.resize` but **I'd rather do it using CSS only**. Kind of like how the "col-sm-" classes work in Bootstrap.

Is there a way to do this using CSS only?

```js
Split(['#a', '#b'], {
  gutterSize: 8,
  cursor: 'col-resize'
})
```

```css
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .split {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;

    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .content {
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #e4e4e4;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .gutter {
    background-color: transparent;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
  }

  .gutter.gutter-horizontal {
    cursor: col-resize;
    background-image: url('http://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/grips/vertical.png');
  }

  .gutter.gutter-vertical {
    cursor: row-resize;
    background-image: url('http://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/grips/horizontal.png');
  }

  .split.split-horizontal, .gutter.gutter-horizontal {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/split.js"></script>

<div id="a" class="split split-horizontal">
  Pane #1
</div>
<div id="b" class="split split-horizontal">
  Pane #1
</div>
```

P.S. If it matters I'm using Bootstrap framework and jQuery-ui on my page.

Comment: Would setting direction:'vertical' in Split.js when the screen is narrow be a good solution? You would also have to remove the split-horizontal class when the screen is narrow.

Comment: Yes, that is how i'm doing it but for that I have to destroy the splitter and create new on window.resize everyime. So I'm looking for a CSS only solutions (like the "col-sm-" class) in bootstrap..

Comment: See if this example helps. It shows vertical and horizontal split panels with only CSS: https://gist.github.com/jpnelson/52d6f38820c6d028bdf8

Comment: @supersan Check this issue https://github.com/nathancahill/split/issues/80 may solve youur question